# Is there is a way to validate xml with xsd schema element with minoccour='1'

Tags: coldfusion, xsd, coldfusion-9, xsd-validation

I have an Xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema id="Peoples" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Peoples">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="People">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="firstname" minOccurs="1" >
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                      <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>       
              </xs:element>  
              <xs:element name="lastname" minOccurs="1" >
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                      <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>       
              </xs:element>  
             <xs:element name="midinitial" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>  
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="email" minOccurs="0" >
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>  
              </xs:element> 
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the xml file is

```
<Peoples xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
    <People>
        <firstname>James</firstname>
    </People>
</Peoples>
```

The xml validation it gives 
:1:142: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'People' is not complete. One of '{lastname, midinitial, email}' is expected.

but in this the firstname and lastname is the requied field.
There is a way to validate xml only required field alone

Comment: If you have both required fields (`firstname` and `lastname`) does it validate? I suspect that the problem is just the error message

Comment: yes, firstname and lastname is the required field but Xsd validation doesn't show the error as lastname it error with option element also "One of '{lastname, midinitial, email}' is expected". Expected result is lastname alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that the validator is validating incorrectly.  Your problem is that you don't like its error messages.  Your options are to try another validator to see if it produces a validation message for this case that you like better, or to get used to the fact that error messages sometimes don't tell us what we wish they did, and sometimes tell us things we wish they didn't.